# What is the logic to update three images of same ID?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, logic

I am trying to update 3 images of same product_id. I have a different product_table and Product_images table. The product_images table has 5 fields; image_id, product_id, name, images, ord. I am trying to update images for any specific product_id. The problem I was facing before was that it set the same 'Image' for all of the three 'images', that why I add 'ord' filed and it solver that problem. Now I have a new problem. I am unable to understand where to write 
update image' query. If I write it inside for loop then it runs 'Update Query' 6 times and if I write it outside for loop then its unable to find out $ord[] variable.
Kindly tell the way to resolve this problem.
Given below is the part of code I am working on.

```
/*
 * ------------------- IMAGE-QUERY Test 002 --------------------
 */
if (isset ( $_FILES ['files'] ) || ($_FILES ["files"] ["type"] == "image/jpeg"))
{
    $i = 1;
    /*
     * ----------------------- Taking Current Order_id ------------------------
     */

    // $order_sql= "select MAX(ord) from product_images";
    $order_sql = "SELECT ord from product_images where product_id=$id";
    $order_sql_run = mysql_query ( $order_sql );
    echo mysql_error ();
    for($i = 1; $i <= $order_fetch = mysql_fetch_array ( $order_sql_run ); $i ++)
        // while ($order_fetch=     mysql_fetch_array($order_sql_run))
        {)
        echo 'ID ' . $order_id [$i] = $order_fetch [(ord)];
    }

    /*
     * ----------------------- Taking Current Order_id ------------------------
     */
    foreach ( $_FILES ['files'] ['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ) {
        // echo $tmp_name."<br>";
        // echo 'number<br>';
        echo $image_name = $_FILES ["files"] ["name"] [$key];
        $random_name = rand () . $_FILES ["files"] ["name"] [$key];
        $folder = "upload/products/" . $random_name;
        move_uploaded_file ( $_FILES ["files"] ["tmp_name"] [$key], "upload/products/" . $random_name );
        echo '<br>';
        echo $sql = "update product_images set name= '$random_name',images= '$folder' where product_id=$id andord=$order_id[$i]";
        if ($query_run = mysql_query ( $sql )) {

            echo '<br>';
            echo 'Done';
        }
        else {
            echo mysql_error ();
        }
        // $i=$i+1;
    }
}


 /*-------------------
IMAGE-QUERY Test 002
--------------------*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all doing an assignment in an echo statement is very bad style (makes it hard to read)

```
echo 'ID ' . $order_id [$i] = $order_fetch [(ord)];
```

better:

```
$order_id [$i] = $order_fetch [(ord)];
echo 'ID ' . $order_id [$i];
```

Second thing:

You use `$i=1;` for your `for` statement.
Note that a Array's index starts with 0 in PHP so this should be `$i=0;` (don't forget to alter the condition).
Should look like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $order_fetch = mysql_fetch_array ( $order_sql_run ); $i ++)
```

and in your `for` statement there is this:

```
{)
```

think it should just be

```
{
```

Concerning your `UPDATE` statement:

You have a typing error in your statement:

```
$sql = "update product_images set name= '$random_name',images= '$folder' where product_id=$id andord=$order_id[$i]";
```

should be

```
$sql = "update product_images set name= '$random_name',images= '$folder' where product_id=$id and ord=$order_id[$i]";
```

(Space between and and ord= missing)

Next, you use `$order_id[$i]` but do not re-define `$i` after you used it in the for-loop. You have to do `$i = 0;` somewhere before you use it and then `$i++;` at the end of your loop.

If you want to replace the existing images and are not absolutely sure that the number of old and new images is the same (or take care of this somehow), you should rather do a `DROP` on the existing images and then `INSERT` the new ones.

Additionally, your foreach statement defines $key as representation of `'tmp_name'` but in the code you use
    $_FILES ["files"] ["name"] [$key]
or
    $_FILES ["files"] ["tmp_name"] [$key]
(are they intentionally different?)
which should actually be
    $_FILES ["files"][$key]
since $key is the name of the current file.